# Stack Overflow tells me to add more details when I trying to indent other user's question

Tags: support, code-formatting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229206/how-i-can-make-authentication-using-my-own-class-in-laravel) has bad indentation of code. However, I cannot save the modified (with code indented) question because it is mostly code.

Why this question could be submitted and why I cannot submit the modified version?

Comment: What error message are you getting exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules about minimum change (are relaxed) as your reputation increases.

At your current reputation, you need to propose a more substantive change than just modifying whitespace.